# List subdomains attached to a google apps domain?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Referring to the admin SDK APIs, I don't see anything that would allow me to list the subdomains defined for the google apps domain (via the CPanel in Domain Settings->Domain Names).

Is there any way to collect this information directly?  Even the older provisioning API doesn't support any listing of subdomains and/or domain aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no domain-specific API calls that allow you to list out secondary domains and domain aliases. However, you can try listing all [users](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_all_users) (with aliases) and [groups](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups#get_all_domain_groups) (with aliases) in order to see which domains are in use. Technically, this may not be all domains (some may not have any users/groups associated with them yet). But for practical purposes it should serve.

Obviously the performance would be much better if you could perform a single API call and get all domains but there's currently no method for that. This is the only workaround I'm aware of.

Comment: Unfortunately it's the only workaround that I'm aware of as well :(